# Barchart no se muestra correctamente

Tags: javafx

Hola amigos de StackOverflow, tengo un problema.. estoy intentando mostrar un gráfico (Barchart) en Javafx, cuando cargo la función en el método Initialize perfecto. Pero cuando le añado un **Mouse Event** al método que genera el gráfico las etiquetas de la fecha no se muestran correctamente y esto no pasa cuando cargo el método directamente en el Initialize:

Este es mi código en el Controlador `IndicadoresController`

en esta función capturo los datos de la Base de datos:

```
public void generaindicador() {
            String Bd="jdbc:sqlserver://DESKTOP-8PJDQNJ:1433;databaseName=QUORA";
            String Usuario="sa";
            String Pass="milkas87";
            String Query= "SELECT FECHA_EJECUTADA ,  COUNT(PRIORIDAD) AS CANTIDAD FROM RINCIDENTES WHERE PRIORIDAD='ALTA' GROUP BY FECHA_EJECUTADA ORDER BY FECHA_EJECUTADA ASC"; 
            String Query2= "SELECT FECHA_EJECUTADA ,  COUNT(PRIORIDAD) AS CANTIDAD FROM RINCIDENTES WHERE PRIORIDAD='MEDIA' GROUP BY FECHA_EJECUTADA ORDER BY FECHA_EJECUTADA ASC"; 
            XYChart.Series<String,Integer> DatosPrioridad = new Series<String,Integer> ();
            XYChart.Series<String,Integer> DatosPrioridad2 = new Series<String,Integer> ();

            Connection Conexiontabla = null;
            try {
                Conexiontabla=DriverManager.getConnection(Bd, Usuario, Pass);
                PreparedStatement ps =Conexiontabla.prepareStatement(Query);
                ResultSet rs = ps.executeQuery();
                while (rs.next()) {
                    String y=rs.getString("FECHA_EJECUTADA");
                    int a=rs.getInt("CANTIDAD");

                    DatosPrioridad.getData().add(new XYChart.Data<>(y,a) );

                }
                indicadorsoporte.getData().add(DatosPrioridad);
                DatosPrioridad.setName("PRIORIDAD ALTA");
               }catch(SQLException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
               }


             try {
                    Conexiontabla=DriverManager.getConnection(Bd, Usuario, Pass);
                    PreparedStatement pd =Conexiontabla.prepareStatement(Query2);
                    ResultSet rss = pd.executeQuery();
                while (rss.next()) {
                    String x=rss.getString("FECHA_EJECUTADA");
                    int z=rss.getInt("CANTIDAD");
                    DatosPrioridad2.getData().add(new XYChart.Data<>(x,z) );

                }
                indicadorsoporte.getData().add(DatosPrioridad2);
                DatosPrioridad2.setName("PRIORIDAD MEDIA");
                fechas.setLabel("Fechas");
                cantidades.setLabel("Cantidades");
            }catch(SQLException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
      }
```

Si cargo la funcion directamente en el metodo initialize todo va perfecto, pero cuando le paso el siguiente metodo como les dije la etiqueta de la fecha no se muestra apropiadamente y es lo que no entiendo.

aqui lo que hago es validar que si el combobox tiene la opcion `"REPORTE DE INCIDENTES"`  genere el grafico con un llamado al MouseEvent `setOnMouseClicked`

este es el codigo:

```
 public void llenacombox() {
          solicitudindc.getItems().add("REPORTE DE INCIDENTES");

      }



     public void generaincidentes() {
         generarind.setOnMouseClicked(e->{
              if(solicitudindc.getSelectionModel().getSelectedItem().toString().equals("REPORTE DE INCIDENTES")) {
                  generaindicador();
              }
              });  
      }
```

y este es el metodo initialize:

```
public void initialize(URL location, ResourceBundle resources) {

        generaincidentes();
        llenacombox();


    }
```

en realidad no se que estoy haciendo mal, se les agradece una orientación por acá por favor?, gracias.

Por aca les dejo las imagenes:

Directo en el initialize:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Con llamado de Mouse Event:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Answer (score 1):

Saca el método    `generaincidentes();` del método `initialize`